# Notification badge counter in Microsoft Teams

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams, badge, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on a custom webApp for Microsoft Teams, I would like to manipulate the badge notification for my App (btw I am not sure if it's the right name), I need to add a counter like teams does for new messages or another symbol to indicate different actions in my app.

[image]

Is there a way to do this? using a sdk, api, (@microsoft/teams-js, etc...)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don't have any API to display notification when some action happens in an app. You can raise an [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) for this if this needs to be considered as a feature request. If you want to Send activity feed notifications to users in Microsoft Teams please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications).